# Why doesn't `make modules_install` install a properly named folder in my /lib/modules when compiling linux kernel?

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, archlinux

I am trying to compile my own kernel according to the [Arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Traditional_compilation) and am running into a problem that it causing `mkinitcpio` to fail.

As some background context I have taken these steps

1. Downloaded the linux source code from github
2. Ran `make clean && make mrproper`
3. Ran `make localmodconfig` to generate a .config file
4. Edit the `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""`in.config file to `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="gabe"`
5. run `make`

At this point everything compiles as expected. Now it was my understanding that the kernel would be named `4.18.0-gabe` as the naming scheme is `<kernel-version>-<local-version>` but that doesn't seem to be the case here. On this next step, when `make modules_install` is run, which from what I can tell is supposed to a directory containing the compiled kernel modules that will be used by the kernel in `/lib/modules` for the initalram disk. The name of the file created should correspond to the name of the kernel, so in my case the file should be `4.18.0-gabe` but after running `make modules_install` I find:

```
[gabe@arch linux]$ make modules_install
  ...
  INSTALL sound/soundcore.ko
  DEPMOD  4.18.0-11133-gc1fecabecc35
[gabe@arch linux]$ ls /lib/modules
4.14.65-1-lts               4.18.3-arch1-1-ARCH    extramodules-ARCH
4.18.0-11133-gc1fecabecc35  extramodules-4.14-lts
```

So you can see that `make modules_install` made a folder called `4.18.0-11133-gc1fecabecc35` despite my localversion being set to `gabe.` This ultimately results in `mkinitcpio` to fail with a "not a valid kernel directory" error because it relies on the directory names to specify acceptable version numbers.

Why is this happening and how can I change it so that `make modules_install` add a properly named folder called `4.18.0-gabe`?

Edit: This is on a clean build of Arch running on Virtualbox

Comment: did you try making and installing modules and kernel with `KERNELRELEASE=4.18.0-gabe` flag ?

Comment: @yashC I did not. My .config file generated doesn't have that flag though.

Comment: I did not mean in config file but append that to make commands you use.

Comment: @yashC No that doesn't work either. That seemed to just modify the config file? But it results in a folder called `4.18.0gabe-11133-gc1fecabecc35`